# What is this Android email address picker? Is this a native widget?

Tags: android, dialog, picker

Can anyone tell me if this email address picker (the dialog, not the stuff behind it) is a standard Android widget and if yes, how it is called / which class it is?

I removed the mail addresses on the following screenshot for privacy reasons.

[image]

Comment: I think this is an implicit intent with the `ACTION_PICK`, `CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_TYPE` and `ContactsContract.Profile`. Check out the info on [common intents - Pick Contact Data](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#PickContactDat).

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann Thanks, actually I found out how it was created in my case, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it internally maybe uses what @Alexander Hoffmann commented, yet I can say that in my case - after tracking it down in the source - it is a [`HintRequest`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/HintRequest) from the Google APIs.